# Converter SQL to LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Como faço para converter o SQL abaixo para LINQ?

```
SELECT 
`clientes`.`Nome`,
`clientes`.`Cpf`,
`clientes`.`email`,
`clientes`.`Id` as clienteId,
`cartoes`.`Id` as CartaoId,
SUM(`historicoTransacaoCartao`.`Valor`) AS `saldo`
FROM
  `clientes`
  INNER JOIN `cartoesClientes` ON (`clientes`.`Id`=`cartoesClientes`.`ClienteId`)
  INNER JOIN `cartoes` ON (`cartoesClientes`.`CartaoId` = `cartoes`.`Id`)
  INNER JOIN `historicoTransacaoCartao` ON (`cartoes`.`Id` = `historicoTransacaoCartao`.`CartaoId`)
GROUP BY
  `clientes`.`Nome`,
  `clientes`.`Cpf`,
  `clientes`.`email`,
  `clientes`.`Id`,
  `cartoes`.`Id`
```

Existe algum site/software que eu possa fazer este tipo de conversão?

Comment: de uma olhada nessa discussão: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296972/sql-to-linq-tool pode ser útil

Comment: A questão é que uma tradução automática do SQL para o LINQ geralmente terá que executar mais *transliteração* do que a tradução - gerando exemplos de como NÃO escrever consultas LINQ. Por esse motivo, há poucas (se houver) ferramentas que poderão converter de maneira confiável o SQL em LINQ. Mas eu recomendo muito o Linqpad para aprender LINQ.

Comment: Você tem as entidades, podendo disponibilizar [editando a sua pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/397656/edit)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Confira também no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/DAajcg).

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var clientes = new[]
            {
                new { Id = 1, Email = "nome1@email.com", Nome = "Nome 1", Cpf = 1L },
                new { Id = 2, Email = "nome2@email.com", Nome = "Nome 2", Cpf = 2L },
                new { Id = 3, Email = "nome3@email.com", Nome = "Nome 3", Cpf = 3L },
                new { Id = 4, Email = "nome4@email.com", Nome = "Nome 4", Cpf = 4L },
                new { Id = 5, Email = "nome5@email.com", Nome = "Nome 5", Cpf = 5L },
            };

            var cartoesClientes = new[]
            {
                new { Id = 1, ClienteId = 1, CartaoId = 1 },
                new { Id = 2, ClienteId = 1, CartaoId = 2 },
                new { Id = 3, ClienteId = 2, CartaoId = 3 },
                new { Id = 4, ClienteId = 2, CartaoId = 4 },
                new { Id = 5, ClienteId = 4, CartaoId = 5 },
                new { Id = 6, ClienteId = 4, CartaoId = 6 },
            };

            var cartoes = new[]
            {
                new { Id = 1, Numero = 1L },
                new { Id = 2, Numero = 2L },
                new { Id = 3, Numero = 3L },
                new { Id = 4, Numero = 4L },
                new { Id = 5, Numero = 5L },
                new { Id = 6, Numero = 6L },
                new { Id = 7, Numero = 7L },
                new { Id = 8, Numero = 8L },
                new { Id = 9, Numero = 9L },
                new { Id = 10, Numero = 10L },
            };

            var historicoTransacaoCartao = new[]
            {
                new { Id = 1, CartaoId = 1, Valor = 100m },
                new { Id = 2, CartaoId = 5, Valor = 100m },
                new { Id = 3, CartaoId = 1, Valor = 100m },
                new { Id = 4, CartaoId = 3, Valor = 100m },
                new { Id = 5, CartaoId = 3, Valor = 100m },
                new { Id = 6, CartaoId = 4, Valor = 100m },
                new { Id = 7, CartaoId = 1, Valor = 100m },
            };

        var query = from cliente in clientes
                    join cartaoCliente in cartoesClientes 
                        on cliente.Id equals cartaoCliente.ClienteId
                    join cartao in cartoes
                        on cartaoCliente.CartaoId equals cartao.Id
                    join historico in historicoTransacaoCartao
                        on cartao.Id equals historico.CartaoId
                    let x = new
                    {
                        cliente.Nome,
                        cliente.Cpf,
                        cliente.Email,
                        cliente.Id,
                        CartaoId = cartao.Id,
                        historico.Valor
                    }
                    group x by new { ClienteId = cliente.Id, CartaoId = cartao.Id } into g
                    select new
                    {
                        g.First().Nome,
                        g.First().Cpf,
                        g.First().Email,
                        g.First().CartaoId,
                        Saldo = g.Sum(s => s.Valor)
                    };

            Console.WriteLine("Nome CPF E-mail CartaoId Saldo");

            foreach (var q in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}; {1}; {2}; {3}; {4}",
                    q.Nome, q.Cpf, q.Email, q.CartaoId, q.Saldo);
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```